# remain on the same page when cancel button clicked in sharepoint login

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

in my sharepoint site, there is anonymous access. When the user clicks "Cancel" button in login dialog box, 401 unauthorized is coming. I want the page to remain on the welcome page of the sharepoint site with anonymous access, when he clicks cancel button. how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog box you are seeing is the normal NTLM authentication dialog and when the user clicks "cancel" it is the correct behavior to redirect to a different page because the HTTP Request code 401 is correct in this case.

What you can do is write a custom error page for HTTP response code 401.

Custom error pages are kind of hard with Sharepoint 2007, see the following blogs for instructions how to implement them:

- [Custom Error Page Adapter](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/02/12/custom-error-page-adapter/)
- [Custom 401 for MOSS 2007](http://rajeshagadi.blogspot.com/2009/11/custom-401-for-moss-2007.html)

Comment: If it is the answer you were seeking, think about accepting the answer with the check-mark on the left.